# Gnu indent function call parameters on separate lines

Tags: c, indentation, gnu

I could not find any option in gnu indent to have:

```
result = some_function(prm1,
                       prm2,
                       prm3);
```

Or something like this:

```
result = some_function(
           prm1,
           prm2,
           prm3);
```

Is it possible with gnu indent? Thank you.

Comment: This is annoying me as well, my guess is that there is no simple and elegant solution (indent can work with asumption of 80 char line and this would mess with it) + many people use tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: No, but let it be 100, 1000 chars long (--line-length option), I just want every argument on a separate line.

Comment: What I ment is that it's not just about us and thus I don't expect to see this in indent (unless you go for it and write it :P)

Answer (score 0):

From the `indent` man page:

> ```
>           p1 = first_procedure (second_procedure (p2, p3),
>              third_procedure (p4, p5));
>
> With `-lp´ in effect the code looks somewhat clearer:
>
>           p1 = first_procedure (second_procedure (p2, p3),
>                                 third_procedure (p4, p5));
> ```
>
> When a statement is broken in between two or more paren pairs (...), each extra pair causes the indentation level extra indentation:
>
> ```
>         if ((((i < 2 &&
>                 k > 0) || p == 0) &&
>             q == 1) ||
>           n = 0)
>
> The option `-ipN´ can be used to set the extra offset per paren.
> For instance, `-ip0´ would format the above as:
>
>         if ((((i < 2 &&
>           k > 0) || p == 0) &&
>           q == 1) ||
>           n = 0)
> ```

Comment: It does split long lines of arguments, but still may leave several parameters on the same line...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Eclipse CDT IDE, they use their own indentation engine afaik.

[image: look at bottom - Settings for parameters]

Comment: Bounty for active participation! I looked in gnu-indent code, a bit messy for me... gnu-indent + uncrustify produce ALMOST what I want.